# Code completion not working for js_of_ocaml in typerex

Tags: ocaml, typerex, js-of-ocaml

Is it possible to enable type completion in Typerex for external modules? In particular I am trying to use js_of_ocaml.

I can see local identifiers in code completion, so it is definitely enabled, but when I type (for example) `Dom_html.` I don't get a list of the module's contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1 of TypeRex does not provide completion on files with syntax extensions, unless you play some tricks with camlp4.

Version 2 of TypeRex will work better, as it will based on a relaxed syntax of OCaml, and usually most standard syntax extensions are compatible with this relaxed syntax.

Version 2 is not yet released, but you can still try it in the branch `typerex2` of the repository.